# Incrementing pointers to pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, while-loop

I've been going through Kernighan and Ritchie book in C and got lost in pointers to pointers that point to char arrays.

Let's take this sample code:

```
char str1[] = "This ";
char str2[] = "is ";
char str3[] = "a cat.";

char *ptr1 = str1;
char *ptr2 = str2;
char *ptr3 = str3;

char *ptrall[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 };
```

Question:
How do I print all of the arrays using, say, while?

The book tells me (quote):

> ```
> while (...){
>    printf("%s\", *ptr++);}
> ```

So, this `*ptr++` is supposed to increment pointers within `**ptr`. But When I try to build it in VS it says there's the "lvalue" mistake.

What do I misunderstand here? How should I increment pointers stored in **?
Am I limited to `printf("%s", ptr[i++])` only?

Comment: What is `ptr`?.

Comment: I can't see any ptr variable declared in your snippet. I guess what you need is going through the ptrAll allocating a cursor (something you move by incrementing it to scan data) of type pointer to (char) pointer, point it at begginning of array and then scan it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake here. The PTR mentioned in the question is from the Book. Eventually I try printing using the following code:
printf("%s", *ptrall++);

Comment: @Matt: `ptrall` in your example is an *array*, not a pointer to pointer. You cannot increment an array. Your question title mentions "pointers to pointers", but so far there are no pointers to pointers in your posted code. So, what "pointers to pointers" are you talking about?

Comment: @AnT You're right. I guess I was wrong to begin with. It's just that the book describes array of pointers as a pointer to pointer. I've checked it again and it does promote incrementing array of pointers without declaring **.

Comment: @Matt: Is there any chance the "array of pointers" in the book was actually *a function parameter*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: How do I print all of the arrays using, say, while?

It depends on how the array `ptrall` is defined.

If the array `ptrall` is defined like

```
char *ptrall[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, NULL };
```

then it can be outputted the following way using a while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str1[] = "This ";
    char str2[] = "is ";
    char str3[] = "a cat.";

    char *ptr1 = str1;
    char *ptr2 = str2;
    char *ptr3 = str3;

    char *ptrall[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, NULL };

    char **ptr = ptrall;

    while (*ptr) printf("%s", *ptr++);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
This is a cat.
```

If the array `ptrall` is defined as in your question that is like

```
char *ptrall[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 };
```

then it can be outputted the following way using a while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str1[] = "This ";
    char str2[] = "is ";
    char str3[] = "a cat.";

    char *ptr1 = str1;
    char *ptr2 = str2;
    char *ptr3 = str3;

    char *ptrall[] = { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 };

    char **ptr = ptrall;

    while (ptr != ptrall + sizeof( ptrall ) / sizeof( *ptrall ) ) printf("%s", *ptr++);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

As for the expression used in this call

```
printf("%s", *ptrall++);
```

then array designators are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not apply preincrement and postincrement operators to an array designator.

Answer (score 1):

To use this you need to terminate your array of pointers;

```
char *ptrall[] = {ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, NULL};

for(char**ptr=ptrall;*ptr;) printf("%s\n",*ptr++);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the apparent problem though ("the lvalue mistake").

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're right.  He must not have declared `ptr` as a `char**` creating the lvalue mistake.  Odd that the title of the question is incrementing pointers to pointers.

Comment: Terminating  array of pointers doesn't help. The lvalue mistake is still there. What should I have declared it as?

Comment: @Matt, It needs to be a `char **` like in the above `for` loop